# Filter data while using pagination Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I am new to Codeigniter and I am trying to figure out a way to use pagination and also filter some data. I have pagination setup to show all records in a table. I want to be able to filter those records using a specific column in the table. The column is an `int`. My controller is `clients` and the method is `index` so going to `http://localhost/clients` will produce a list of clients in a table. When I go to another page to display more results the URL changes to something like `http://localhost/clients/50` depending on what page I am on. Now, I have one argument for my controller method which is `$client_status`, which again is an `int`. Since CI is using the second segment of the URL for pagination, how to I pass the argument for filtering by client status? Here is what the code looks like:

```
    public function index($client_status = false) {
       if(!$client_status) {
          $data['clients'] = $this->clients_model->list_clients($config["per_page"], $page);
       } else {
          $data['clients'] = $this->clients_model->list_clients($config["per_page"], $page, $client_status);
       }
```

And my model:

```
public function list_clients($limit, $start, $client_status = false) {

        if(!$client_status) {

            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('clients');
            $this->db->join('client_status', 'clients.client_status_id = client_status.client_status_id');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                return $query->result();

            } else {

                return false;

            }


        } else {

            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('clients');
            $this->db->join('client_status', 'clients.client_status_id = client_status.client_status_id');
            $this->db->where(array('clients.client_status_id' => $client_status));
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                return $query->result();

            } else {

                return false;

            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to pass your parameters into the query string. In your config for the pagination class make sure to set these following parameters

```
$config = array(
  'page_query_string'       => TRUE,
  'query_string_segment'    => 'page', // the query string param for the page numbers
  'reuse_query_string'      => TRUE,
)
```

With the config your URL's would be similar to

http://example.com/clients?param=value&page=2